# Apache poi - print layout, more than one print area in the same sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to develop a complex report, and I need to set up the print areas for the excel file. I must divide the xls file in 3 part, but if I do setPrintArea(..) the new area subscribe the old and the result is that I have in the print preview only the last page. How can I set more than one print area? This is the code:

```
protected void createCustomerSheet(String label) {
    createSheet(label);
    getCurrentSheet().getPrintSetup().setPaperSize(PrintSetup.A4_PAPERSIZE);
    getCurrentSheet().getPrintSetup().setFitHeight((short)1);
    getCurrentSheet().getPrintSetup().setFitWidth((short)1);
    getCurrentSheet().setAutobreaks(true);
    getCurrentSheet().setFitToPage(true);
}
```

then I call 3 times

```
 wb.setPrintArea(activeSheetIndex, startColumn, endColumn, startRow, endRow);
```

I also tried to add break rows, but it doesn't work..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Excel maintains only one [print area](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10451/print-only-selected-areas-of-a-spreadsheet-in-excel-2007-2010/) for a spreadsheet.  So Apache POI's Excel API provides the ability to [set one print area](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html).

It sounds like you might be trying to define different pages of a report.  If so, you'll need to set row and/or column breaks in each Sheet in which you want this done.  Use the following methods of [Sheet](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html), assuming `sheet` is your `Sheet` instance:

```
sheet.setAutobreaks(false);
sheet.setRowBreak(rowIndex);
sheet.setColumnBreak(columnIndex);
```

You may call each of those last 2 methods multiple times to establish multiple breaks.

Comment: I tried with row and column break, maybe there was something wrong. I will try again, but in the excel I see the chance to "add to printArea", and I didn't find anything about this in the apache poi documentation

Comment: Your answer is good, the only thing I need to add to my sheet it was setScale

Comment: @Vargan Can you be more specific on how to use setScale()?

Comment: Thank you sir!!! The first line, setAutoBreaks(false) is very important here as adding breaks without them wont work properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can set multiple print ranges like this:

```
try (final Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("in.xls"))) {
    wb.setPrintArea(0,  "$E$6:$F$12,$H$16:$I$25,$J$18:$L$26");
    wb.write(new FileOutputStream("out.xls"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I set the print area for my sheets.

```
// set print area
workbook.setPrintArea(
    workbook.getSheetIndex(sheet.getSheetName()), //sheet index
    0, //start column
    x, //end column
    0, //start row
    i  //end row
);
```