# POI Apache - Excel - number of page

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using POI Apache for create *.xls. I need write to file about few pages and when I begin write new page, I need write something, but it isn't directly top. It's few rows. How can I do it? It is some function for find page by row (cell)?

Thank you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899293/apache-poi-print-layout-more-than-one-print-area-in-the-same-sheet/14900320#14900320)

Comment: I don't know still, how can I find number of page. What procedure should I do?

Comment: I don't know how to find out which row belongs to which page, if there aren't any explicit page breaks (see link above). But may be you need to explain a bit more, what you mean by "it's few rows". e.g. a page header/footer (with a page number) or a repeating table head

Comment: Ok, I will see to page breaks, I thinked, it's needs, but, what next? How can I find page number now, with page breaks?
Yes, by "few rows" I think 2-3 rows, where I write some text to some cell (ex. first row - text in 1. cell, 2.cell, last cell, second row - text in first and last cell).

Comment: Apart from the trivial way, where you know how many rows (with the same height) fit on each page (with a given paper format) and therefore can calculate the page breaks easily ... I thought about some [vba macro in hidden cell](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/387958-page-numbers-in-cells.html) and a repeating table header, but the repeating header can't address relatively the others rows. Maybe you can sum up the font sizes of each row, i.e. determine which cell of a row contains the most chars (incl. line breaks) and calculate its (font layout) size?!

Comment: and btw. maybe something like [jasperreports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) would be a solution for your problem, too